# Macbook Pro Optical Drive Makes Sounds When Drive is Empty

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, audio

I have a MacBook Pro (1.83Ghz) running Mac OS X 10.5.7. The optical drive makes sounds like it's accessing data off a disk. However, the drive is empty.

The sound is intermittent. Sometimes I won't hear it for a few days.
Then the sound will start and may continue all day.

Things I have tried:

I reset the PRAM by rebooting and holding down cmd-option-P-R

I tried to download the most recent firmware and Apple does not appear to be supporting the 1.83 Ghz MacBook Pro any longer as there have been no firmware updates in the last year.

Comment: Your MacBook Pro is still supported - if you have AppleCare it should even still be within it's 3 year warranty. Firmware updates don't denote whether or not a product is supported.

Answer (score 3):

While this behavior is "normal" when the slot-loading optical drive is being powered up (boot, reboot and wake from sleep usually) it should not be constantly doing it when your MBP is running. If it is I would first reset PRAM…

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=2238

… and failing that contact Apple Care.

( or ) Something else you can try is to actually insert a CD/DVD (I'd do it with one of each), use then for a bit and then eject. The drive might intermittently think there's something in it which is why the noise

[Source](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1110915)

AND  Check here also  : [Semi-random clicking sound from Macbook Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/44202/semi-random-clicking-sound-from-macbook-pro)